# Making a webservice that is clients platform independent

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, cross-platform

i am making a webservice, mostly is done but the thing is `[WebMethod]` returns a .net `DataTable` so client using other platform won't be able to call it, I need the architecture to be `SOA`([details here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_oriented_architecture)) like it takes a request and gives a response. I can use `xml serializable` classes to get the data but i have no idea how would they fit in. any ideas?

Comment: What if you return the data in JSON format?

Comment: Unless you're stuck using .NET 2.0, you should not use ASMX web services. You should be using WCF for all new development.

Comment: never used JSON would prefer xml, in any case how would i do that return a `string`

Comment: @JohnSaunders any WCF tutorial which does this?, i have been looking for wcf web services and found cliams based services is that the same thing?

Comment: A tutorial that does what? Returns a DataTable? Don't _do_ that. It's platform-specific. See the resources at [tag:wcf].

Comment: @John Saunders: "You should be using WCF for all new development" - I have to disagree with this statement. WCF is not the only option for creating HTTP services in .NET.

Comment: @AdamRalph: I meant using WCF as a _replacement_ for ASMX, meaning a replacement for SOAP. I'm not suggesting an alternate architecture (though of course, in various circumstances, might be well justified).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return an custom class and just use arrays and not lists or dictionary's. Just did this and PHP, Java and .Net developers will be ale to work with your object.

You can also [expose JSON](http://blog.clauskonrad.net/2010/11/how-to-expose-json-endpoint-from-wcf.html) there is a walk though on how to do that.

Also take a look at [Web API](http://wcf.codeplex.com/releases) you may decide to use it instead.

On another note: PHP can have trouble with its native SOAP support which is 1.1, so use basichttp bindings or the client will need to use NuSoap which is SOAP 1.2 instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to expose your HTTP services to as wide a range of clients as possible, then I would recommend dropping SOAP based messaging altogether and instead represent your data as XML, JSON and/or any other content type which you wish to support, according to a schema which *you* define for your data.

IMHO, a very good OSS framework for this purpose is [OpenRasta](http://openrasta.org/).

Answer (score 1):

I would investigate using RESTful services and returning the data as a platform agnostic format like XML or JSON as others have suggested.

Additionally, take a look at using ASP.NET MVC for your services in favor of WCF.  It's a much better system than WCF in my opinion:

http://iwantmymvc.com/rest-service-mvc3

Answer (score 0):

WCF can easily support SOAP ([basicHttpBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.basichttpbinding.aspx)) or REST ([webHttpBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.webhttpbinding.aspx)) style service interfaces with out-of-the-box bindings. You can certainly build ASMX, but the usages are dying off. I just wrote a WCF REST/SOAP interface to replace a legacy ASMX that was using `DataTables` (*because of interoperability issues*). Now interoperability is as simple as having an HTTP Client or a WSDL class generator for your platform.